# Session timeout before given time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication

I am using form authentication with Asp.Net MVC application as given below:

**Code**

```
public void SignIn(string userName, bool isCookiePersistent)
        {

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(14),
                createPersistentCookie, string.Empty);

            HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, isCookiePersistent);
            if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
            {
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
            }

            authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
        }

public void SignOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
```

**Problem:**
The problem is, if I set form authentication timeout to 4 hours, still my users redirected to login page after half-hour after log in.

I have tried by both including `SessionSate` OR execluding `SessionState` in web.config, but noting is happening. Still the problem remain same. Here is my below web.cofig code.

**Web.config (without sessionState element)**

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/LogOn" requireSSL="false" timeout="240" defaultUrl="~/Home/Home" name="__appcookie" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" protection="All">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

**Web.config (WITH sessionState element)**

```
<sessionState timeout="240"></sessionState>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/LogOn" requireSSL="false" timeout="240" defaultUrl="~/Home/Home" name="__appcookie" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" protection="All">
          </forms>
        </authentication>
```

Could anybody please do let me know that it's really important to include `sessionState` and `sessionTimeout` in web.config ? Can't I only use `formAuthentication` through out my application?

No matter if I use `sessionState` or NOT, Even only with `form authentication`, my user redirected to login page after half-hour after logging in application. (BUT I already set 240 minutes as a `form authentication timeout`).

Could anybody please give me some idea or solution on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is idletime too. Are you sure redirects are when user is active? If not you have to set idle time to 4 hours too.

Answer (score 1):

The `forms ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40"` specifies that the ticket expiration date is stored as UTC. The default is `Framework20` which specifies that the ticket expiration date is stored as local time. If you're setting your FormsAuthenticationTicket expiry date manually as you are with `DateTime.Now` while your ticketCompatibilityMode is Framework40, you've got a disconnect between local and UTC (`DateTime.Now` vs. `DateTime.UtcNow`).

It's a gotcha that got me recently. See [this MSDN article for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.web.configuration.ticketcompatibilitymode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try upping the session timeout value in IIS.  The default value for that is 20 minutes.  You could set the web.config to have the session timeout in 4 years, but the IIS session timeout will override it.   Assuming your users are not being active on your site...

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes is the default time for a forms auth cookie which leads me to believe there is something wrong with your configuration.  Can you try simplifying the configuration just for testing?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/LogOn" timeout="240" protection="All" />
</authentication>
```